# Get property name with class name attached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get property name with the class name attached from my model to insert it as a key value in ModelState.AddModelError method.

I tried this code:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> errors { get; set; }

public Validator()
{
    errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

public void PatientDetailRules(PatientDetailModel model)
{
    errors.Add(nameof(model.PatientEligibility.IsBetweenForty), Resources.Ophthalmic.OPH_GOS1_EligibilityError);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> errorlist in vs.errors)
        ModelState.AddModelError(errorlist.Key, errorlist.Value);
}
```

The problem here is it's giving me directly the Property name as "IsBetweenForty". Now I want this name with the class name as "PatientEligibility.IsBetweenForty". Because just property name is not binding to validationmessage helper. Hence it's not showing the error message.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you considered reflection, perchance?

Comment: Yes. You can use reflection. `PropertyInfo` has the information you need.

Comment: Reflection isn´t what OP´s looking for, as it doesn´t handle the case where the property-name or the type-name will change producing an error at *runtime*. `nameof` on the other hand will produce a compile-time error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but isn't it as simple as

```
errors.Add(string.Format("{0}.{1}", nameof(model.PatientEligibility) , nameof(model.PatientEligbility.IsBetweenForty)), Resources.Ophthalmic.OPH_GOS1_EligibilityError);
```

Answer (score 3):

`nameof` (as you noticed)  will just return the name of the variable which is `IsBetweenForty`. You´ll need to concatenate the type-name and the property-name:

```
errors.Add(
    model.PatientEligibility.GetType().Name + "." + nameof(PatientEligibility), 
    Resources.Ophthalmic.OPH_GOS1_EligibilityError)
```